# Android не может найти указанный файл

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Мне нужно считать данные с файла JSON. Но при указании пути он его не находит
Уже проверил, где он ищет файл, ищет там, где он лежит
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

```
val file = File("src\\data.json")
    println("Attempting to read from file in: "+file.getCanonicalPath())
    try {
        val reader = file.reader()
    }catch (e:IOException){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Выхлоп при println:
I/System.out: Attempting to read from file in: /src/data.json

Ошибка:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/data.json (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно различать файловую систему среды разработки и файловую систему андроида. Это абсолютно разные вещи и ваше `src\data.json` лежит у вас в компьютере, а совсем не в эмуляторе и тем более не в телефоне, если вы запускаете приложение на физическом устройстве.

Comment: О, спасибо большое. Об этом не задумывался;)